# Self-Study, Minimal Sufficient Statistic, MLE, Beta, Correct Argument

Tags: self-learning, maximum-likelihood, sufficient-statistics

The following example is taken from [Hogg Introduction to Mathematical Statistics 7e](https://github.com/peach07up/stat420/blob/master/(7th%20Edition)%20Robert%20V.%20Hogg%2C%20Joeseph%20McKean%2C%20Allen%20T%20Craig-Introduction%20to%20Mathematical%20Statistics-Pearson%20(2012).pdf) and the exercise is to show that the MLE is a minimal sufficient statistic. I am not 100% sure about my argument.

Given: $X_1, \dots, X_n \overset{iid}{\sim} Beta(1, \theta)$

1. Deriving the ML-Estimator:

$$
f_X(x) = \frac{ \Gamma(1+\theta) }{\Gamma(1)\Gamma(\theta)} x^0(1 - x)^{\theta -1} = \frac{\theta!}{(\theta-1)!}(1 - x)^{\theta -1} = \theta(1 - x)^{\theta -1} \quad x \in (0,1]
$$

Likelihood function (let $I := {1,\dots, n})$:
\begin{align*}
L(\theta|x_{i \in I}) &= \prod_{i \in I} \theta\cdot(1 - x_i)^{\theta-1} = \theta^n\prod_{i \in I}(1 - x_i)^{\theta-1} \\
\Rightarrow logL(\theta|x_{i \in I})&= n log(\theta) + (\theta - 1)\sum_{i \in I}log(1-x_i) \rightarrow max! \\
&\Rightarrow\frac{n}{\theta} + \sum_{i \in I}log(1-x_i) \overset{!}{=} 0 \\
&\Rightarrow \hat{\theta}_{ML} = -\frac{1}{n \sum_{i \in I}log(1-x_i)}
\end{align*}

which will be positive since $log(x) \leq 0 \quad \forall x \in (0, 1)$.

Factorizing:

\begin{align*}
L(\theta|X_{i \in I}) &= \prod_{i \in I} \theta\cdot(1 - x_i)^{\theta-1} = \theta^n\prod_{i \in I}(1 - x_i)^{\theta-1} = \theta^n\prod_{i \in I}(1 - x_i)^{\theta} \prod_{i \in I}(1 - x_i)^{-1} \\
&\Rightarrow log(L(\theta|X_{i \in I})) =nlog(\theta)+ \theta\sum_{i \in I}log(1 - x_i) - \sum_{i \in I}log(1 - x_i)
\end{align*}

**My argument**:

Thus by the factorization theorem $(\sum_{i \in I}log(1-x_i))$ is a sufficient statistic. Since $\hat{\theta}$ is a function of the sufficient statistic, it is in fact a minimal sufficient statistic (without proof).

Comment: Argue that $\sum \ln (1-X_i)$ is minimal sufficient. Any bijective function of a minimal sufficient statistic is minimal sufficient.